# Levana or Yareach?

Tags: words, hebrew, astronomy, isaiah-yeshaya-the-book, shir-hashirim

In the entire Tanach the moon is generally called Yareach. There are 3 instances where it is called Levana:

- **1)**  [ישעיהו: כד. כג](https://www.sefaria.org/Isaiah.24.23?lang=bi).

> וחפרה **הלבנה** ובושה החמה

- **2)** [ישעיהו: ל. כו](https://www.sefaria.org/Isaiah.30.26?lang=bi&with=all&lang2=en).

> והיה אור **הלבנה** כאור החמה

- **3)** [שיר השירים: ו. י](https://www.sefaria.org/Song_of_Songs.6.10?lang=bi).

> מי זאת הנשקפה כמו שחר יפה **כלבנה**

Why is it called Levana at times when most of the times it is known as Yareach?

Comment: Sometimes also called חודש, no?

Comment: Those are also the only times the sun is called חמה (except once more in Iyov)

Comment: I'm guessing this is just the evolution of the language.  Those are fairly new sfarim.

Comment: well, not "fairly new".  Let's say "relatively new". But there may be a deeper meaning, too.

Comment: Related: https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/96418/is-there-a-difference-between-%D7%99%D7%A8%D7%97%D7%99%D7%9D-and-%D7%97%D7%93%D7%A9%D7%99%D7%9D/101938#101938

Answer (score 2):

I wrote an essay about the different words for the moon. What comes out is that basically ירח focuses on the orbital path which the moon takes in travelling the solar system, while לבנה focuses on the moon’s color, and a third word סהר focuses on its shape. See [*What's in a Word?*](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!forum/whats-in-a-word), "[My Three Suns (and Moons)](http://ohr.edu/this_week/whats_in_a_word/7004)" All three instances to which you refer that the word לבנה appears, the focus is on the physical appearance of the moon, so the word לבנה makes most sense.